# How do I increment my count field of my document from logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I want to update one field of my document/log in elasticsearch from logstash.

My logstash conf file

```
input { 
    http {
    host => "127.0.0.1" # default: 0.0.0.0
    port => 31311 # default: 8080
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { codec => json },
  elasticsearch {
        action => "update"
        bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
        bind_port => 9200
        document_id => "ET00009682"
        index => "in12"
        type => "event"
  }
}
```

I want to increment my count field by one how do I specify that in my output of logstash.

Note: I know to update i need to use this script

```
"script" : "ctx._source.count += 1"
```

but I am not sure where to place it in output of logstash?

Kindly help
thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with the conf:

```
output { 
  stdout { codec => json },
  elasticsearch {
        action => "update"
        bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
        bind_port => 9200
        document_id => "ET00009682"
        index => "in12"
        type => "event"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        script => "ctx._source.count += 1"
        script_lang => "groovy"
        script_type => "inline"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use the metric filter where you have a counter : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html

```
filter {
  metrics {
    meter => [ "thing" ]
    add_tag => "metric"
  }
}
```

You will receive a field name : thing.count which will be your count field

Answer (score 0):

So what i did was fired a curl request from output of logstash to achieve this.